# How to use form authentication with asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use forms authentication in asp.net mvc applications. I have searched a this things but could not get satisfactory answer so can any one please give me brief idea for this. I am a newbie and playing around asp.net mvc.

Please also describe how many authentication is possible with the asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [official MVC tutorial](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-17-cs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked  at this [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2008/02/07/asp-net-mvc-framework-using-forms-authentication.aspx).